# Optimize HTML5 for UIWebView

Tags: ios, uiwebview

Is there any way to optimize `UIWebView`?

I heard that you can use write `HTML5` to optimize the performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of any quick fixes, or easy outs in iOS for making an existing HTML5 App run faster, however there are a [number of](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/html5/) individual things you can do to make it perform better overall (and gain wins when on mobile)